# How to monitor JMX

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I'm new in tomcat and jmx. I need to monitor a JMX on Tomcat, so I add the following text to my config (setenv):

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8008 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

How can I get a information from host? And what soft I need to use? Zabbix isn't preferred option.

Is this config helps java to SEND any data, or it just connector for monitoring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java application does not need any additional software installed.
Java application needs to be started with enabled support for remote JMX monitoring.

As a bare minimum, start it with these options:

CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "

There are many other Java options available (SSL,auth.) after that restart the application to start the service on port 12345.

check the port by netstat -ntlp | grep 12345 in Linux server.